# OpenGL taking screenshot of background instead of executing

Tags: c, opengl

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
clock_t t;


double X1, Y1, X2, Y2;
void delay(int number_of_seconds)
{
    // Converting time into milli_seconds
    int milli_seconds = 1000 * number_of_seconds;

    // Stroing start time
    clock_t start_time = clock();

    // looping till required time is not acheived
    while (clock() < start_time + milli_seconds)
    ;
}
float round_value(float v)
{
return floor(v + 0.5);
}
void MP(void)
{


double x,y,p;
    x=X1;
    y=Y1;
double dx=(X2-X1);
double dy=(Y2-Y1);
p=2*dy-dx;

double steps;

/* Clears buffers to preset values */
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
/* Plot the points */
glBegin(GL_POINTS);
/* Plot the first point */
glVertex2d(x,y);
int k;
/* For every step, find an intermediate vertex */
/* printf("%0.6lf %0.6lf\n",floor(x), floor(y)); */

while(x<X2)
    {
    if(p>=0)
    {
        glVertex2d(round_value(x), round_value(y));
        y=y+1;
        p=p+2*dy-2*dx;
    }
    else
    {
        glVertex2d(round_value(x), round_value(y));
        p=p+2*dy;
    }
    x=x+1;
    }
glEnd();
glFlush();

}
void LineDDA(void)
{
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

double dx=(X2-X1);
double dy=(Y2-Y1);
double steps;
float xInc,yInc,x=X1,y=Y1;
/* Find out whether to increment x or y */
steps=(abs(dx)>abs(dy))?(abs(dx)):(abs(dy));
xInc=dx/(float)steps;
yInc=dy/(float)steps;
/* Clears buffers to preset values */
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
/* Plot the points */
glBegin(GL_POINTS);
/* Plot the first point */
glVertex2d(x,y);
int k;
/* For every step, find an intermediate vertex */
for(k=0;k<steps;k++)
{
x+=xInc;
y+=yInc;
/* printf("%0.6lf %0.6lf\n",floor(x), floor(y)); */
glVertex2d(round_value(x), round_value(y));
}
glEnd();
glFlush();
}
void Init()
{
/* Set clear color to white */
glClearColor(1.0,1.0,1.0,0);
/* Set fill color to black */
glColor3f(0.0,0.0,0.0);
/* glViewport(0 , 0 , 640 , 480); */
/* glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION); */
/* glLoadIdentity(); */
gluOrtho2D(0 , 640 , 0 , 480);
}
void main(int argc, char **argv)
{
char ch='n';
int choice;
/* Initialise GLUT library */
glutInit(&argc,argv);
/* Set the initial display mode */
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
/* Set the initial window position and size */
glutInitWindowPosition(0,0);
glutInitWindowSize(640,480);
do
{

printf("Enter two end points of the line to be drawn:\n");
printf("\n************************************");printf("\nEnter Point1( X1 , Y1):\n");
scanf("%lf%lf",&X1,&Y1);
printf("\n************************************");
printf("\nEnter Point1( X2 , Y2):\n");
scanf("%lf%lf",&X2,&Y2);
glFlush();

/* Create the window with title "DDA_Line" */

printf("!----------------Menu---------------!\n");
printf("!---------------1.DDA---------------!\n");
printf("!------------2.Brehanham------------!\n");
scanf("%d",&choice);
glutCreateWindow("Compare b/w DDA and Bresenham");
/* Initialize drawing colors */
Init();
/* Call the displaying function */
t=clock();
if(choice==1)
glutDisplayFunc(LineDDA);
else if(choice==2)
glutDisplayFunc(MP);
else
printf("\nWrong choice");
t=clock()-t;
  double time_taken = ((double)t)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC; // in seconds

    printf("Algorithm took %f seconds to execute \n", time_taken);
printf("Question?\n");
scanf(" %c",&ch);
delay(3000);  
glutDestroyWindow(1);


}while(ch=='Y');    
/* Keep displaying until the program is closed */
glutMainLoop();
}
```

I am trying to implement comparison between to algorithms. (Midpoint and DDA). But when I try to open the window it takes screenshot of background instead of the actual algorithm. How do I flush the frame buffer to avoid this? I put glFlush in multiple places but that does not seem to do the trick. 
Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Your code is hard to read. Please indent your code properly.

Comment: I see no `glReadPixels` how do you obtaining the screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid you misunderstand how to use GLUT.
What `glutMainLoop` does is invoke your set `glutDisplayFunc` every time the window is asked to repaint.
What you describe as "taking a screenshot of the background" is actually "my window is not being repainted".

One way forward is as follows:

- First collect all user input (coordinates and drawing mechanism) and store them in memory (global variables will do, initially).
- Next, set your `glutDisplayFunc` to a function of your own that will render the stored inputs to screen, keeping in mind the drawing algorithm selected by the user.
- Finally, enter the `glutMainLoop`. This will run until the user exits the program, at which point the loop will exit and you can destroy the window.